# Monitoring a value change on an input element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
US Price: <input type="text" name="us_price" id="us_price" value="1000" onchange="$('#uk_price').val($(this).val()*2);" />
UK Price :<input type="text" name="uk_price" id="uk_price" value="2000" />
```

Here if a user enters a value in US price it will double and set in UK Price. What I want is to write a separate function to monitor the value change in UK price input field. Please help.

for example: if value changed show `alert("Done!")`.

Comment: What have you tried? What issues have you run into? What does your own attempt (code) look like?

Comment: What do you mean, you want to monitor it? Such that when the uk price is changed, the US price is updated as well? Do you want it logged to the console? alerted? Printed to the page? What?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#uk_price').change(function(){
    alert('changed! the value is now: ' + this.value);
    // You can assign the value to the us_price input
    $('#us_price').val(this.value));
});
```

---

Note that the code you have:

```
$('#uk_price').val($(this).val()*2);
```

won't trigger the change event, because it wasn't focused.

This should do the trick:

```
$('#uk_price').focus().val(this.value * 2);
$(this).focus();
```